# Ubuntu Installation error message

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop on a laptop from a bootable USB stick but I am getting stuck at this error message:
(input/output error during write on /dev/mmcblk1)

Can anyone tell me what this mean and what to do next.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for responding GUIVERC. I am not a computer geek so I don't know what "stack or kernel" mean. It's Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop. I just wanted to know what the error code meant and what was my next step. Thank you.

Comment: I think that’s where you’re trying to install Ubuntu - and it looks like it’s an sd card (or some other multimedia card). Are you trying to install it on a media card or an ssd / hdd? If media card, have you checked write  protection isn’t enabled? Do please post more details about your hardware and we’ll try to help - thanks!

Comment: Thanks Will I appreciate it. The laptop is an ACER Aspire E11 and has an INTERNAL  eMMC 32GB SSD Media. It was running Windows 8 and in the Ubuntu setup screen I choose to erase the drive and do a clean install of Ubuntu. Cheers

Comment: I was running Windows 8 and in the Ubuntu setup screen I choose to erase the drive and do a clean install of Ubuntu. I can boot into Ubuntu from the external USB stick and I can see the eMMC SSD drive and contents.

Comment: Ok - so it may be that Windows didn’t shut down completely - if it hibernated, Windows leaves the hard drive in a state that generally prevents other OS’s writing to it. Can you still boot into Windows?

Comment: Hi Will, Unfortunately I can no longer boot into Windows, the system gives the error message "a required file is missing - File: tms.sys Error Code: 0x0000098

Comment: The system also prompt for me to repair with the recovery tool from installation disk which I don't have. The laptop came with everything pre-installed and no media.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not certain this is the problem, but I would try completely deleting the content of that mmc - it may be that the installer doesn't want to use it if Windows left it in an unsafe state. So boot into a live session ('try Ubuntu') and use GParted (included on the live session) to delete all partitions on your mmc card - leaving it all as 'Unallocated space'.

Comment: The other (completely unrelated) thing you might want to check is whether there is a slot for conventional SSD in your laptop. There often is - I opened my dad's laptop to see what upgrade options were - he thought he had a 64GB SSD but it turned out to be a 64GB mmc card -- but there was an empty M.2 drive bay in there so it was a very easy upgrade to a much better storage machine. It's very common for there to be an M.2 slot in a laptop even if sold without a SSD - and M.2 SSD drives are pretty inexpensive now.

Comment: Thanks Will for all your help. I will try your suggestions. Cheers